# Classic Asp - JavaScript : Height and width is always zero in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp-classic

I have an image field in my markup.I am setting its source using javascript. I need its height and width. for that I have used image.height() and image.width() methods. 
it works proper in Internet Explorer but not in chrome, I have tried image.height and image.width method, but not getting any value.
 also I have tried by changing prop method to attr for setting the image src, but it is also gives me the same result. I am pasting my code here.

```
function new()
{
timg = new Image();
    timg.src=fpath; 
}
```

I call that in another method

```
function Size(timg) {

        var con=150;
        th=timg.height;
    alert("th="+th); //in chrome always returns Zero
        tw=timg.width;
    alert("tw="+tw); //in chrome always returns Zero
        }
```

Please advise!

Comment: show your html/css also to working code

Comment: its just the table width and height

Comment: Try using the `Image()` constructor to get the dimensions.

Comment: yes we already use Image() to get the dimensions, it works in IE but not in Chrome, Any idea why it doesn't work in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

have you try:

```
<script>
var tw = document.getElementById('YourElemId').clientWidth;
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = tw;
</script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Browser compatibility. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth

if not success with image id="YourElemId", maybe you can wrap your image with div id="YourElemId" and do document.getElementById('YourElemId').clientWidth . for test div style="border:1px solid #000;max-width:?px;"

I read that clientWidth property do not work for elements with display:inline?, several element inline by default like span, img and others. You can try to set your element id="YourElemId" with style="display:block;"